# How to calculate the sizes of a rectangle that contains rotated image (potentially with transparent pixels)

Tags: c, geometry, rotation, rectangles, cairo

Given `theta` angles in radians, `width` and `height` of the rotated image, how do I calculate the new width and height of the outer rectangle that contains the rotated image?

In other words how do I calculate the new bonding box width/height?
Note that the image could actually be circle and have transparent pixels on the edges.

[image]

That would be: x1, y1.

I am actually rotating a pixbuf with the origin at center using `cairo_rotate()` and I need to know the newly allocated area. What I tried is this:

```
double geo_rotated_rectangle_get_width (double a, double b, double theta)
{
    return abs(a*cos(theta)) + abs(b*sin(theta));
}
```

And it will work in the sense of always returning sufficient space to contain the rotated image, but it also always returns higher values than it should, when image is not rotated in a multiple of 90o and is a fully opaque image (a square).

---

**EDIT:**
This is the image I am rotating:
[image]

Interestingly enough, I just tried with a fully opaque image with the same size and it was OK. I use `gdk_pixbuf_get_width()` to get width and it returns the same value for both regardless. So I assume the formula is correct and the problem is that the transparency is not accounted for. When rotated with a diagonal orientation there are edges from the rectangle of the rotated image that are transparent.

---

I'll leave the above so that it is helpful to others :)
Now the question becomes how to account for transparent pixels on the edges

Comment: [You need to compute the new locations of the four corners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions). Then find the min and max values for x and y.

Comment: I'm really not that good in geometry, haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the bbox of the rotated rectangle, you can compute the coordinates of the 4 vertices and take the bbox of these 4 points.

- `a` is the width of the unrotated rectangle and `b` its height ;
- let `diag = sqrt(a * a + b * b) / 2` the distance from the center to the top right corner of this rectangle. You can use `diag = hypot(a, b) / 2` for better precision ;
- first compute the angle `theta0` of the first diagonal for `theta=0`: `theta0 = atan(b / a)` or better `theta0 = atan2(b, a)` ;
- the 4 vertices are:

  - { `diag * cos(theta0 + theta)`, `diag * sin(theta0 + theta)` }
  - { `diag * cos(pi - theta0 + theta)`, `diag * sin(pi - theta0 + theta)` }
  - { `diag * cos(pi + theta0 + theta)`, `diag * sin(pi + theta0 + theta)` }
  - { `diag * cos(-theta0 + theta)`, `diag * sin(-theta0 + theta)` }
- which can be simplified as:

  - { `diag * cos(theta + theta0)`, `diag * sin(theta + theta0)` }
  - { `-diag * cos(theta - theta0)`, `-diag * sin(theta - theta0)` }
  - { `-diag * cos(theta + theta0)`, `-diag * sin(theta + theta0)` }
  - { `diag * cos(theta - theta0)`, `diag * sin(theta - theta0)` }
- which gives `x1` and `y1`:

  - `x1 = diag * fmax(fabs(cos(theta + theta0)), fabs(cos(theta - theta0))`
  - `y1 = diag * fmax(fabs(sin(theta + theta0)), fabs(sin(theta - theta0))`
- and the `width` and `height` of the rotated rectangle follow:

  - `width = 2 * diag * fmax(fabs(cos(theta + theta0)), fabs(cos(theta - theta0))`
  - `height = 2 * diag * fmax(fabs(sin(theta + theta0)), fabs(sin(theta - theta0))`

This is the geometric solution, but you must take into account the rounding performed by the graphics primitive, so it is much preferable to use the graphics API and retrieve the pixbuf dimensions with `gdk_pixbuf_get_width()` and `gdk_pixbuf_get_height()`, which will allow for precise placement.

Comment: Upvoted, useful addition. However I'm afraid that my edit makes it loose strength concerning my specific problem, but that's okay. I initially used the term square, because that's what pixbufs are, ultimately, but the problem occurs due to the fact that some pixbufs are actually complex figures and have transparency and the bonding box should take them into consideration.

Comment: Tried it and that works too (I had to use `fabs`) ... :)

Comment: If you think it is useful and there is a way for this that you are aware of - add how to account for the edges of a image that is supposed not to be fully opaque rectangle.

Comment: @Edenia: indeed `fabs()` should be used, and `fmax()` too.

Comment: @Edenia: for partially transparent images, there is no magic bullet, you must analyse the rotated bitmap to determine the actual dimensions of the actual image. For the example in the question, it seems the image is close to a disc, so the dimensions of the bird head are unaffected by rotation.

Comment: you are very capable in this area I can see. I suspected I had to analyze it to get the dimensions of the actual image, which actually makes those calculations redundant. I can pass the diagonal as width and height, then call `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface()` get pixdata, scan to find actual image bounding box and update width/height. What do you think? Also can you tell me what's the difference between my formula approach and yours?

Comment: @Edenia: if you want an exact result, scanning the pixmap seems necessary. You might need to pass the diagonal length plus one or two extra pixels to account for anti-aliasing and rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "let cairo compute those coordinates". If you have access to a `cairo_t*`, you can do something like the following (untested!):

```
double x1, y1, x2, y2;
cairo_save(cr);
cairo_rotate(cr, theta); // You can also do cairo_translate() and whatever your heart desires
cairo_new_path(cr);
cairo_rectangle(cr, x, y, width, height);
cairo_restore(cr); // Note: This preserved the path!
cairo_fill_extents(cr, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
cairo_new_path(cr); // Clean up after ourselves
printf("Rectangle is inside of (%g,%g) to (%g,%g) (size %g,%g)\n",
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

The above code applies some transformation, then constructs a path. This makes cairo apply the transformation to the given coordinates. Afterwards, the transformation is "thrown away" with `cairo_restore()`. Next, we ask cairo for the area covered by the current path, which it provides in the current coordinate system, i.e. without the transformation.

Comment: Does this account for transparent pixels?

Comment: No. It only looks at the extents of the rectangle. I do not think there is anything in cairo that would give you information about the transparent pixels.